# Subclass not inheriting all methods

Tags: java, class, inheritance, subclass, super

I have a class titled "Account" :

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Account {

    public int id = 0; //Declare default id as 0
    public double balance = 0; //Declare default balance as 0
    public double annualInterestRate = 0; //Declare default annual interest rate as 0
    public Date dateCreated = new Date(); //Declare date

    //No argument constructor for Account
    public Account() {
    id = 0;
    balance = 0.0;
    annualInterestRate = 0.0;
    }   

    //Constructor that accepts ID, Balance, and Annual Interest Rate
    public Account(int newID, double newBalance, double newAnnualInterestRate) {
    id = newID;
    balance = newBalance;
    annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
    }  

    //Get ID
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //Set ID
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //Get Balance
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    //Set Balance
    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    //Get Annual Interest Rate
    public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
        return annualInterestRate;
    }

    //Set Annual Interest Rate
    public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
        this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    }

    //Get Date Created
    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    //Withdraw method
    double withdraw(double amount) {
    return balance -= amount;
    }

    //Deposit method 
    double deposit(double amount) {
    return balance += amount;
    }

    //Interest rate method
    double getMonthlyInterestRate() {
    return (balance * annualInterestRate) / 12;
   }

} //End Account class
```

I've then created two different sub-classes "PreferredCustomer" and "CommercialCustomer". These two classes should inherit all methods (deposit, withdraw, monthly interest rate, and all getters and setters) of the main "Account" class. The only difference with the sub-classes, is that they have a pre-determined interest rate.

```
public class PreferredCustomer extends Account {

    public double annualInterestRate;

    public PreferredCustomer() {
    }

    public PreferredCustomer(int id, double balance) {
    super();
    this.annualInterestRate = .04;
    }

} //end PreferredCustomer Class
```

I have a feeling the way I currently have it set up is not accurate. When testing, the withdraw and deposit methods work, but despite entering a starting balance of $20,000, it still sets the starting balance at $0 and does not calculate the interest rate.

I'm testing the class as such:

```
public class TestingAccountClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Create accounts
    CommercialCustomer myCommercialCustomerAccount = new CommercialCustomer(1124, 
          20000.00);

   //Invoking deposit method from account class
   myCommercialCustomerAccount.deposit(3000.00);

   //Display account balance, monthly interest, and date created
   System.out.println("\n\n----Commercial Account---");
   System.out.println("Account Created On: "
       + myCommercialCustomerAccount.getDateCreated());
   System.out.printf("Balance: $%.2f", myCommercialCustomerAccount.getBalance());
   System.out.printf("\nMonthly Interest: $%.2f"
       ,myCommercialCustomerAccount.getMonthlyInterestRate());
```

When testing the class in this way, the deposit method works, but nothing else from the account class (other than withdraw) appears to be working. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `PreferredCustomer` should not define an `annualInterestRate` - it inherits Account's `annualInterestRate`. In addition, `PreferredCustomer` should be calling `super(id, balance, .04)`

Comment: At the moment, if I take the annualInterestRate code out, it still does not spit out the correct balance :( The thing is, the subclass needs to have it's own interest rate and not inherit that of the main class. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do:

```
CommercialCustomer myCommercialCustomerAccount = new CommercialCustomer(1124, 20000.00);
```

However,

```
public PreferredCustomer(int id, double balance) {
    super();
    this.annualInterestRate = .04;
}
```

You do not do anything with the balance!

You could perhaps change it to:

```
public PreferredCustomer(int id, double balance) {
    super();
    this.balance = balance;
    this.annualInterestRate = .04;
}
```

But you would be writing to `balance` twice.

Also, it is a bad idea to have two variables with the same name (base vs child) -> `annualInterestRate`.

EDIT ------------------------------------------ EDIT

I would recommend something like this:

```
public Account() {
    this(0, 0d, 0d);
}  

public Account(int id, double balance, double interestRate) {
    this.id = id;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.annualInterestRate = interestRate;
}   

public PreferredCustomer(int id, double balance) {
    super(id, balance, 0.04d);
}
```

EDIT2 ------------------------------------------ EDIT2

This is wrong. You are doing integer division.

```
return (balance * annualInterestRate) / 12;
```

Change to this:

```
return (balance * annualInterestRate) / 12d;
```

or this:

```
return (balance * annualInterestRate) / 12.0;
```

Comment: I do apologize if this seems a bit trivial, college student, so I'm still learning :) I think I might have a misunderstanding of how to construct the subclass. Currently, I've set it up similar to the examples my professor has given me, but obviously there's more to it that I'm missing :/

Comment: That seems to mostly fix it. The balance is updating now, but the interest is still not calculating. Backing to the drawing board I suppose :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. I understand where I went wrong now, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In `PreferredCustomer` there is no mechanism for setting the balance; you are ignoring the `balance` constructor argument.  You haven't directly assigned the `balance` instance variable  and you haven't invoked the superclass constructor.  So the balance is 0.

In the `PreferredCustomer` constructor, either call the superclass constructor that sets the balance, or set it there in the constructor itself, or call `setBalance`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is somewhere here :

```
public PreferredCustomer(int id, double balance) {
    super();
    this.annualInterestRate = .04;
    }
```

Shouldn't you put something inside the super() call? (default values)

Answer (score -1):

ALERT!

For starts you NEVER make your non-final member variables public. I nearly just had a heart attack.

when you type

```
this.foo
```

The scope continues to climb up the inherentence tree until it finds an accessible member. So
this-->super-->super.super-->super.super.super --... etc

I can tell you how to syntactically solve your problem or tell you how to do this much much better.

I choose the later.

declare a

```
public abstract double getAnnualInterestRate();
```

in your base class

then change your implementation of getMonthlyInterestRate as such (calling this new method)

```
   //Interest rate method
    double getMonthlyInterestRate() {
    return (balance * getAnnualInterestRate()) / 12;
   }
```

in your subclass simply implement this abstract method and return your interest rate.

This will allow you to polymorphically vary the rate and make your implementation future proof. Functions may do anything at all to produce their return value where as member variable are just a bit of data and nothing more

And, please, make all your member variable private

Comment: I certainly appreciate the advice, though I suppose my knowledge my be lacking slightly. What specifically do you mean by "NEVER make your non-final member variables public"? Are you referring to the variables in my Account class, such as id, balance, etc? When I originally created the Account class, I made these variables Private, I was however under the impression the needed to be set to Public in order to be inherited by the main class. I will fix this immediately :)

Comment: Still a bit off. You are still performing integer division here.

Comment: Making them public will certainly make them accessible to subclasses. However, it will also make them accessible to the whole world. Member variables represent the internal state of your object and should only ever be manipulated by that object through mechanisms it supports (like setters) or none at all (ideal). Controlling variable access in the method limits the where and how data can be manipulated and lets you do things like proxying, lazy loading validation, etc. Follow up with me for discussion. Traditionally, subclass access is done by declaring a member protected